# Chrome Extension: Close Window After XHR

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I want to make an XHR from a chrome extension when the user clicks a button. Then I want to close the window.

If I close the window after the send, the request is canceled. If I close the window in the request listener, the extension crashes.

How to close the window?

```
var requestListener = function() {
  bkg.console.log(this.readyState);
  window.close() // <-- When I put this here, the extension crashes.
};
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var data = {foo: "bar"};
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("post", "http://localhost:8080", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = requestListener;
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    window.close(); // <-- When I put this here, the request is canceled.
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give me a crash. But I've got this warning:
`Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`
You can send a message to the backround, from where you can run
`chrome.tabs.remove( sender.tab.id, ...)`

Comment: What is needed to see this error? I haven't been able to get error messages to show in the console.

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.118 m) and just created test extension with your code in content script. Yes, this warning is in the console of the target page.

Answer (score -1):

A wild guess: Maybe the window closes too soon so something like...

```
<body onbeforeunload="SendFunction();">
```

...may help. Good luck.